# Limit characters in Ninja Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, textarea, ninja-forms

I installed the 3.4.24.3 version of Ninja Forms in my WordPress, and I've created a Contact form, in the part of the message, that it´s a text area I need to limit the number of characters or words, but I don´t find in the advanced menu or configuration a way to limit the characters in this part. I need to limit the extension of the message. I also search an ad-on and documentation, but only I find the limit of submissions, and I don´t need that. Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check to see if you have enabled Dev Mode by setting it to on, you can find out how to do this here: https://ninjaforms.com/docs/developer-mode/

- In your Wordpress Admin Dashboard go to Dashboard > Ninja Forms > Settings and look for **Form Builder "Dev Mode"** to see if checkbox is ticked.
- Return to your forms and then click on the form field where you want to limit characters or words.
- In the options menu, you should see RESTRICTIONS and in the dropdown, options to limit characters or words.
- Apply your settings including `TEXT TO APPEAR AFTER COUNTER` which is customizable and will be displayed on your form. e.g. 200 Character(s) remaining
- Once completed, click Done, Preview your form to confirm changes and then Publish.

Find out more here under paragraph text: https://ninjaforms.com/docs/field-types/#html